# How do I save a screenshot in Ingress on iPhone without uploading it anywhere?

Tags: ios, ingress

Since a couple of month Ingress has this share button on certain screens (most useful one is probably the player profile). If you press that, it opens a selection of where you want to share the picture, and takes a full-size screenshot.

On **Android**, you can just press the back-button and not do anything and the screenshot will end up as an image file in your phone's library (but in a separate folder). However, on **iOS** I cannot find the file. If you select G+ or similar target, you can upload it. But it doesn't go in the image library and it doesn't seem to go anywhere else.

I want to archive those screenshots. Where do they go?

Comment: Use the [screenshot](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289) method?

Comment: @Ben as in taking a regular screenshot yourself? The agent profile screen has a scroll bar, and the share functionality stitches it together as one looong image. Taking a screenshot manually will result in losing the lower (or upper) part of the data. That doesn't work for my purposes unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m running iOS 7 and for me the screenshots do end up under Photos even when I press Cancel in the share settings. Perhaps you declined, when Ingress first prompted you for access to your photos. Check it from under iOS Settings -> Privacy -> Photos.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem like it is possible to save directly to your photos, however a workaround would be to send it as a text message or an email then save it from there. While this is still "uploading" you are not posting this on social media as you can email this to yourself.